# How to get all commit ID's after certain date and display only the files that were changed?

Tags: git, git-log

I need to get names of all files changed after certain date. Seems like if I have commit_id I can use
`git show --name-only <commit_id>`
This gives me :

```
commit sfffwefwew3134343(origin/<branch_name>)
Author: ...............
Date: ..................
      <Commit Msg>
abc/xyz/abc.sql
```

So basically two questions:
Is there a way to get just the file like `abc/xyz/abc.sql`?
If so, how can I get all commit id's after certain date so that I can iterate over all the id and grab the files changed?

OR

Is there a better way to find files that was changed after certain date?

Comment: Consider reading the documentation for `git log`. It lets you (a) list the commits after a certain date, (b) list the commits in which a certain file changed, and (c) set the format in which the information about each commit should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, try

```
git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only --since=<date>
```

...which will produce an output like this, each commit producing its own files list separated by an empty line

```
file1.txt
file2.txt

file2.txt
dir/file3.txt
file9.txt

file1.txt
```

...which you can (if needed?) regroup by sending the result of the command through `| sort -u` to get

```
dir/file3.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
file9.txt
```

---

*Notes*
`--pretty=format:""` *is here to turn off each commit's info (other than file names)*
*and the doc for* `--since` is [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---sinceltdategt).

Comment: Thanks, this is great. However When I tried this cmd, seems like there are few files that was not picked up. Not sure why, as there were 4 files in one dir that was changed and only 3 got picked by this cmd. (They were in merged id, would that matter?)

Answer (score 2):

This command will give you the output you're looking for:

```sh
git log --format="%+H" --name-only --since=<date>
```

For example:

```
bcc1f17f6d6d3b8f5d55364aef5852902428afc6

dir/foo.txt
dir/bar.txt

473b9ffd0f7dade2fa896081b0a75ee1c122a4f4

dir/baz.txt

44db7a7e2cb8243ccba4621f0df9e08669513a89

dir/subdir/fiz.txt
dir/faz.txt
```

If you prefer to see the abbreviated commit ID, you can substitute `%+H` with `%+h`:

```sh
git log --format="%+h" --name-only --since=<date>
```

There's a lot you can do to format the output of `git log`. I recommend reading up on the different placeholders that you can use with the `--format` option in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats).

Comment: Thanks, this is great. However When I tried this cmd, seems like there are few files that was not picked up. Not sure why, as there were 4 files in one dir that was changed and only 3 got picked by this cmd. (They were in merged id, would that matter?)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git diff --name-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---name-only) using [date](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtltdategtemegemmasteryesterdayememHEAD5minutesagoem) as the revision. Like this:

```
git diff --name-only "HEAD@{2020-01-01}"
```

Comment: I keep my answer here for completion, but *this* is the best way I guess. Thanks @phd for the reminder, I always forget this construct (`<ref>@{<date>}`)